# Gulp trouble in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, gulp, visual-studio-2019

I try run gulpfile.js in Visual Studio 2019 by Task Run Explorer but I get errors in Output:

```
Failed to run "D:\...\Gulpfile.js"...
cmd.exe /c gulp --tasks-simple
gulp[5856]: src\node_contextify.cc:633: Assertion `args[1]->IsString()' failed.
 1: 00007FF61B19121A v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+4810
 2: 00007FF61B16A5B6 node::MakeCallback+4518
 3: 00007FF61B16A66F node::MakeCallback+4703
 4: 00007FF61B13D838 node::DecodeWrite+12952
 5: 00007FF61B995782 v8::internal::OptimizingCompileDispatcher::Unblock+60562
 6: 00007FF61B996908 v8::internal::OptimizingCompileDispatcher::Unblock+65048
 7: 00007FF61B995C3D v8::internal::OptimizingCompileDispatcher::Unblock+61773
 8: 00007FF61B995B5B v8::internal::OptimizingCompileDispatcher::Unblock+61547
 9: 000000BDBACDC5C1
```

Also I try run from console and I get the same error. Funny things is that my second notebook I don't have any trouble tu run it. However only different is Visual Studio - this gulpfile.js work good  only in Visual Studio 2017.

Anyone have any idea how to solve this? I really don't want to have installed two Visual Studio on my computer. It's pointless.

Comment: `npm install natives` solve my problem

Comment: I have this same issue too.   I'm thinking maybe gulp v3 is not made for vs2019.    Still digging.